# Prove $p(x) = x^3+x+1\in\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

We have:

$$p(x) = x^3+x+1\in\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$$

First of all, I tried to prove that there are no roots in $\mathbb{Z}_5$, so I tried all of them:

$$p(0) = 1\\p(1) = 3\\p(2) = 1\\p(3) = 1\\p(4) = 4$$
So since there are no roots, I can't reduce this polynomial to a linear polynomial times a 2nd degree one. T

Comment: Yes, that's a valid approach.